# r notebook plotting with lines

Tags: r, rstudio, rnotebook

When plotting some lines via `lines` to an existing plot object in plain R this works just fine. However, in R notebooks from Rstudio this will fail. How can I use this functionality in notebooks?

Comment: This appears to be a valid question which really pertains Rstudio (for once).

Comment: Please ping me if this question gets closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has bit me in the rear many a time. What I found works is running all plot related lines at once (select and run) and not step-by-step. Alternatively you can press the green arrow (Run current chunk) or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>.

My RStudio version is 1.0.44.